# Add pannel in Liferay 7.2 doesnt show the basic web content

Tags: liferay-7.2

I have a web developed in Liferay 7.2. Suddenly, in the server instance, when i try to add contents to pages the add panel doesn't show the Web Contents. Any help? thx

Even cleaning the work and temp and restarting the tomcat the content is not showed

Comment: Try reindexing the search index.  And note [help/on-topic], as this question is not programming related. Consider bringing it to the Liferay community at https://liferay.dev as it's off topic here

Comment: Many thanks, reindexing the search index fix the trouble nicely